# Binding Click Events on Ajax loaded Material

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load some content through ajax:

```
<form action="functions.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="function" value="login_instructor">
        <h2 class="dark">Instructor Login</h2>
        <br>Instructor Full Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name">
        <br>Instructor Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="pass">
        <br><a class="btn btn-inverse btn-large" href="#">Login as Instructor &raquo;</a>
      </form>
```

And in my header, I have a included a .js file:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.btn").click(function(){ $(this).parent().submit(); });
});
```

I assume that ready() event is called every time the ajax request is done, therefore the binding should occur again. However, when I load the content, clicking the button does not submit the form.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try moving the event handling higher:
$(document).on("click", "a.btn", function(){ $(this).parent().submit(); });

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer!

Comment: Please post it as an answer so I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: Mark the iamjpg guy :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the 'on' method like so:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.btn", function() {
    // Do something.
});
```

[Documentation here.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Good luck!

Comment: That's a much nicer solution than mine. Thanks. I never thought of doing that and will make my code neater in future.